# Dynamically Set Slider Max Value On Load

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm trying to manually set the slider max value in Qualtrics using JavaScript.

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23318398/1066291)  but no "CS_{postTag}" element has that name on my survey question. I also tried doing a search for any element that may be related to the above answer, that is: `jQuery("[maxValue]")` and `jQuery(["name*='{postTag}'"])`, but neither of these returned anything helpful.

I also put a break in Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnLoad(function() {}) and then explored the [Qualtrics Javascript API](https://s.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/QuestionAPI/classes/Qualtrics%20JavaScript%20Question%20API.html#method_getQuestionContainer) in my watch window without any luck.

The crux of the problem is that Qualtrics doesn't use an `<input type="range">` for its slide. Instead the slider seems to be a collection of div elements that Qualtrics controls through custom JavaScript events. This means most of the relevant controls are hidden somewhere in JavaScript.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The example you referenced may work under SE. Under SE, CS_{postTag} references a slider object that gets created by some JavaScript. Add the parameter Q_JFE=0 to the url to run the survey under SE.

Comment: @T.Gibbons sorry for the delayed response. We gave this a shot and still weren't able to get it to work. We're going to move on to another survey method. Thanks for taking the time to comment